# doctrine prevent from updating joined entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have entity with

```
Liability {
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Objection",  mappedBy="liability", cascade={"persist"})
 *
 * @var
 */
private $objections;
```

and

```
Objection {
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Liability")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="liability_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=true)
 */
private $liability;
```

i create form to add objection

i add to new objection exist liability.

```
$obj = new Objection();
$liability = $doctrine....->find($liabilityId);
$obj->setLiablity($liability);
```

in a edit form user can change details of liability i save it as array. 
but when i save objection i update liability i don`t want do it.

i try before save get fresh from database but it not read fresh.

Comment: ok i found when i push to form clone of liability it not updating database values on save objection.

Comment: As far you've shown us, you are not persisting `$obj` at all. Did you miss to include that code in your question?